# Bind Function Link

Tags: javascript, function, bind

I have a piece of JS that looks like this...

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){ 
$("#button1").bind('click', function(){ 
//function code
}
}
```

My problem is, I want to have an image that (when clicked) executes this function but I can't figure out the syntax of how to do that. Can someone please help?

Comment: Use `.trigger()` to call it: `$("#button1").trigger('click')`

Comment: Not sure I follow. What would the image's HTML be?

Comment: Is `#button1` your image?  What is `#button1`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#button1
```

in jquery means that there is somewhere a tag where the following is the id:

```
id="button1"
```

so if the code above is part of your image tag, then the click event applies to your image.